# Get text from anchor tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following anchor tag

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

I know how to get the href from an anchor take:

```
alert($(this).attr("href"));
```

But how do I get the text from the anchor tag, i.e. how do I get "Google"?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for this:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

If you wanted the markup ([`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) removes tags and such), use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
alert($(this).html());
```

In *this* case there's no difference, if instead you had this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google <span>(External)</span></a>
```

Then there would be:

```
$(this).text() //"Google (External)"
$(this).html() //"Google <span>(External)</span>"
```

Comment: how can i get only Google?

Comment: Any answers to get the immediate text only?

Answer (score 0):

On using the .text() as mentioned, I got the text of all the anchor tags combined in my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 jumbotron jumbotronUserRaces list-group list-group-
userRaces" id="listGroupUserRaces">
                <a href="" class="list-group-item active">First item</a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#listGroupUserRaces").click(function () {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

OUTPUT:

- First item
- Second item
- Third item