# How to get the text from anchor tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, displaytag

The following is my anchor tag........

```
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<p><span id="hix-pagination"><span> <a id="id1" class="prev" href="{1}">&#9668;&#9668;</a>
```

And I tried the following using jquery but did not get any positive result.....

```
alert($('#id1').text());
      alert($('#id1').html());
      alert($('#id1').val());
```

Comment: Are you sure you have latest jquery.js imported in your workspace ?

Comment: text() and html() should work - what do they output in your example? Chances are it's a mistake at a more basic level, such as not importing jQuery as @TheDarkKnight suggests. Could also be you forgot to wrap it in `$(function() { ... } )` to make sure the dom is loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652372/how-to-get-anchor-text-href-on-click-using-jquery) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871228/get-text-from-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 4):

You have right selector, if you have jQuery included successfully then you may need [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) also check if you get html out of DOM

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dqXVp/)**

```
$(function(){
   alert($('#id1').html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link :

[How to get anchor text/href on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652372/how-to-get-anchor-text-href-on-click-using-jquery)

[Get text from anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871228/get-text-from-anchor-tag)

href:

```
$(function(){
$('div.res a').click(function(){
alert($(this).attr('href'));
 });
});
```

Text:

```
$(function(){
$('div.res a').click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#id1").click(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
            return false;
            }); 
        } 
);
```

Comment: I have included inside                                  $(document).ready(function(){                  alert($('#id1').text());
      alert($('#id1').html());
      alert($('#id1').val());}                                            And I want the alert message when the page is loading and not after clicking the link....