# How to get the value of formatted cell value of a row in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am populating JQ grid with student details. I have formatted one of the columns to be as hyperlink using a function.

```
return "<a href='#' onClick='xxx(\"" + rowObject._id + "\")'>"
            + cellvalue + "</a>";
```

So my grid will contain a column which has a text "abc" (say) formatted as hyperlink.
I need to display the value of the selected row in a jquery dialog.

When I try to get the value of this formatted cell using row.link, it gives me the whole anchor tag specifications like

```
var selrow = jQuery('#studentGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var row = jQuery('#studentGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', selrow);
var link= row['studentInfo.link'];
alert(link);
```

gives me

```
<a href="#" onclick="xxx("rowId")">abc</a>
```

How can I get the value abc alone from the row. Please help.

Comment: You can use `.text()` for this purpose.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871228/get-text-from-anchor-tag

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ : Added more!

Comment: @Art713 : You mean link.text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the text inside the a tag, then try this

```
var link= row['studentInfo.link'].replace(/^.+(?:>)(.+(?=<\/a)).+$/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" data-value="rowid_here">Text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").click(function(){
    textval=$(this).text();
    alert(textval);

    rowid=$(this).data("value");
    alert(rowid);
});
</script>
```

hope this help you

you can also get rowid

Comment: I am not taking it on click of the anchor Tag. I want to fetch it from jquery row. I have added additional js code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you are using jquery(which is obvious)

```
var link= row['studentInfo.link'];
link = $(link).html();
console.log(link);
```

it works for me, it returns the value that it's inside the tag